# Insert and Delete Query stopped working in AccessDataSource

Tags: asp.net, database, ms-access

I have a submit button that inserts user entered data into a database. It was working perfectly fine until I migrated the project to the host server. The select query is still functional and displaying my data in the GridView (I checked by manually inserting some data into the database on the host server), I am unable to insert or delete data via the client-side page. It's an access database and I am connecting to it using the Visual Studio AccessDataSource.

Also, I don't receive any errors when loading the page or when I hit submit, its just that nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="jotest.aspx.vb" Inherits="jotest" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
            function imposeMaxLength(Object, MaxLen) {
                return (Object.value.length <= MaxLen);
            }
-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<div>
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/login.mdb" 
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM tblComments WHERE ID = @ID" 
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO tblComments(comment, commentor_name, comment_date) VALUES (@comment, @commentor_name, @comment_date)" 
 SelectCommand="SELECT ID, commentor_name, comment, comment_date FROM tblComments">
<InsertParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="commentor_name" />
<asp:Parameter Name="comment" />
<asp:Parameter Name="comment_date" />
<asp:Parameter Name="ID" />
</InsertParameters>
<DeleteParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="ID" />
</DeleteParameters>
</asp:AccessDataSource>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<div style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 600px;">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowSorting="True">
<AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="comment" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="comment" ItemStyle-Width="80px" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="commentor_name" HeaderText="Comment" SortExpression="commentor_name" ItemStyle-Width="300px" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="comment_date" HeaderText="Date" SortExpression="date" ItemStyle-Width="175px" />
<asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
</Columns>
<EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
<FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
<PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
<RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
<SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
<SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
<SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
<SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
<SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
</asp:GridView>
</div>
<br />
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DefaultMode="Insert">
<InsertItemTemplate>
Name:<asp:TextBox ID="commentor_nameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("commentor_name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
<br />
Comment:<asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" runat="server" onkeypress="return imposeMaxLength(this, 150);" Text='<%# Bind("comment") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="4" Columns="50"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidTimeDate" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("comment_date") %>' />
<asp:Button ID="butSubmit" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Submit" />
</InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the account that is accessing the file has read and write access on the host server folder where the mdb file is located.